# (R-studio) Incorporating overnight returns in high-frequency data

Tags: programming, high-frequency

Turning here since I haven't been able to find any help online.

I'm currently dealing with a high-frequency data set in R of some stock indicies and I'm currently trying to clean the data so that I will be able to work with it.

So, to get to the problem, I'm trying to incorporate the overnight returns of the indicies (i.e. prices in between 15:00 and 09:00 the following day) as done by [Hansen & Lunde (2005)](https://academic.oup.com/jfec/article-abstract/3/4/525/907786?redirectedFrom=PDF) - that is, taking the median of the overnight prices and storing it as the 09:00 observation the next day.

Does anyone have any R-code on how to deal with this problem?

PS. I have been able to store the overnight median price as the 23:00-observation the previous day (i.e. the day that the overnight trading started). However, I haven't been able to change the date and time of these observations so that they end up at 09:00 the next day. An example is listed below:

2006-12-29 14:30:00 17320.00
2006-12-29 14:35:00 17315.00
2006-12-29 14:40:00 17315.00
2006-12-29 14:45:00 17322.50
2006-12-29 15:00:00 17325.00
2006-12-29 23:00:00 17321.25 <- THIS OBSERVATION I WOULD LIKE TO END UP AT 09:00 THE NEXT DAY

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have any R-code on how to deal with this problem?

It depends on what data structures you are using, but one approach is the following:

1. Define a two-column array to hold date and time separately. This array will have as many rows as your current array. Alternatively, *cbind()* these two columns to your array.
2. Define an array *distinct_dates* that will only have distinct dates in it (*levels()* is useful here).
3. In the two-column array, set the date field to the next day --which you will get from *distinct_dates*-- in rows where timestamp starts with '23:'.
4. In the two-column array, set the timestamp field to 09:00 in rows where timestamp starts with '23:'.
5. Set the values of original date-timestamp column by merging the fields you processed in steps 3 & 4.
6. Cleanup: Remove the two temporary columns (if you *cbind*-ed them to your original array) or delete the two-column array, accordingly.